# Creating an instance using factory with assisted parameters throws exception with Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I have an interface with two implementations

```
public interface JobConfiguration {
    void execute();
}
```

DecryptJobConfiguration:

```
public class DecryptJobConfiguration implements JobConfiguration {
    @Inject
    public DecryptJobConfiguration(@Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                                   @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath,
                                   ImageDecrypter imageDecrypter) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(){
        // DO stuff
    }
}
```

EncryptJobConfiguration:

```
public class EncryptJobConfiguration implements JobConfiguration {
    @Inject
    public EncryptJobConfiguration(@Assisted("inputString") String inputString,
                                   @Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                                   @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath,
                                   ImageEncrypter imageEncrypter,
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I have a factory interface:

```
public interface JobConfigurationFactory {
    @Named("encrypt")
    JobConfiguration createEncrypt(@Assisted("inputString") String inputString,
                                   @Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                                   @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath);

    @Named("decrypt")
    JobConfiguration createDecrypt(@Assisted("secretKey") String secretKey,
                                   @Assisted("inputImagePath") String inputImagePath);
}
```

Which is installed in Google Guice:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
        .implement(JobConfiguration.class, Names.named("encrypt"), EncryptJobConfiguration.class)
        .implement(JobConfiguration.class, Names.named("decrypt"), DecryptJobConfiguration.class)
        .build(JobConfigurationFactory.class));
```

In another class where I wish to create an instance of `EncryptJobConfiguration` I inject `JobConfigurationFactory`:

```
@Inject
public CommandLineArgumentValidator(JobConfigurationFactory jobConfigurationFactory){
    this.jobConfigurationFactory = jobConfigurationFactory;
}
```

and later in one of the methods I call `createEncrypt`:

```
jobConfigurationFactory.createEncrypt("A", "B", "C");
```

I would expect this to return me an instance of `EncryptJobConfiguration`, but it results in this exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>
> at
>   com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.invoke(FactoryProvider2.java:824)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.createEncrypt(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.infojolt.imageencrypt.CommandLineArgumentValidator.validateArguments(CommandLineArgumentValidator.java:29)
>     at
>   com.infojolt.imageencrypt.CommandLineArgumentValidatorTest.validateArgumentsReturnsInputStringWhenAllRequiredFieldsAreSet(CommandLineArgumentValidatorTest.java:55)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)

This is my first time using Google Guice and I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding how it should work? How should I create a new instance of `EncryptJobConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I missed an important piece of information from the question. I was using Google Guice 4.0. Upgrading to v4.2 resolved the problem without any other code changes.